# Why can't user access restricted folder via smb when member of a group?

Tags: centos, samba, smb

I have a server running CentOS 7 with a samba share folder set up. There is a subfolder that I would only like certain users to be able to access. However, when I mount the samba share folder I am unable to access the folder (I am able to access it via ssh). Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

The users are all members of a group and the group is the owner of that folder. Only member of the group can read, write, and execute the folder and its contents. When I add the users to smb.conf as valid users = user1, user2, user3 it 1) does not allow them access via smb and 2) kicks all of the users accessing the share as guests.